# How to to locate and click the select boolean check box using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click primefaces select boolean check box using id but i could not able to click I'm getting some exception caused by:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.id: runDARtest1
```

I increased second 30 also but again getting same issues

```
driver.get("http://localhost:5080/MOIA2-WEB/");
driver.findElement(By.id("moia2Form:loginForm:tabViedID:userName")).sendKeys("cherie.chen");
driver.findElement(By.id("moia2Form:loginForm:tabViedID:password")).sendKeys("Password1");
driver.findElement(By.id("moia2Form:loginForm:tabViedID:loginButton")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("moia2Form:lnkMarketClearing")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("moia2Form:system_Result_runinfo")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("runDARtest1"))).click();;
```

Xhtml code: select boolean check box there in inside the table

```
<tr>
    <td><label class="switch"> <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                                            class="runDARclass"
                                            value="#{systemResultManagedBean.runDAR}" id="runDAR" />
    <span class="slider round" id="runDARtest1"></span>
    </label></td>
    <td><p:spacer width="5px" /><span>DAR</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Kamal How can we convince you not to add `<blockquotes>` to the error trace logs. Doing so debugging becomes difficult as the _error messages_ in the _error stack trace_  gets **word wrapped**.

Comment: Noted. Will take care.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label.switch span.slider.round#runDARtest1"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@class='switch']//span[@class='slider round' and @id='runDARtest1']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: i added above mentioned both code but still getting below exception: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //label[@class='switch']//span[@class='slider round' and @id='runDARtest1']

Comment: @RameshKumar How about the `cssSelector`?

Comment: getting same exception

Comment: @RameshKumar Can you just copy and paste my code from the answer. The answer I provided wouldn't ever throw **exception: Cannot locate an element** rather it can throw _TimeoutException_.

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@class='switch']//span[@class='slider round' and @id='runDARtest1']"))).click();

Comment: @RameshKumar Use this line of code in your test and let me know the status.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //label[@class='switch']//span[@class='slider round' and @id='runDARtest1'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //label[@class='switch']//span[@class='slider round' and @id='runDARtest1']

Comment: this table inside the child frame.

Comment: @RameshKumar You need to switch to the `<iframe>` before trying to click on any element within the frame. Update the question with the HTML including the `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: I added this line driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeCenter"))); before the click element its working for me.